# How to use Decodable Protocol to create common class for same Json properties with different keys

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4, decodable

```
{
    "actions" : {
        "upvote" : {
            "delete" : true,
            "read" : true,
            "create" : true,
            "update": true
        },
        "read" : {
            "delete" : true,
            "update" : true,
            "read" : true,
            "create" : true
        }
    }
}
```

I have this Json response coming from server and below are the model structs created using Decodable protocol

```
struct Actions: Decodable {
    let upvote: UpvoteStatus
    let read: ReadStatus

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case upvote
        case read
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.upvote = try container.decode(UpvoteStatus.self, forKey: .upvote) {
        self.read = try container.decode(ReadStatus.self, forKey: .read)
    }
}

struct UpvoteStatus: Decodable {
    let delete: Bool
    let update: Bool
    let read: Bool
    let create: Bool
}

struct ReadStatus: Decodable {
    var delete: Bool
    var update: Bool
    var read: Bool
    var create: Bool
}
```

This works great but create lot of duplicate code as UpvoteStatus and ReadStatus structs has similar properties and JSON coming from server is similar except for the different keys.

Is there any way possible I can create a common status struct add status property to ReadStatus and UpvoteStatus class

```
struct Status: Decodable {
    let delete: Bool
    let update: Bool
    let read: Bool
    let create: Bool
}
```

Now I want to have have something like below, so that I can remove duplicate code.

```
struct UpvoteStatus: Decodable {
    let status: Status
}

struct ReadStatus: Decodable {
    let status: Status
}
```

Comment: Just `let upvote: Status ` and `let read: Status ` in `struct Actions`?

Comment: I want status property inside UpvoteStatus and ReadStatus so if extra properties gets added then I can add there.

Comment: @Tj3n using subclass is one option to achieve the solution, but need to change struct to class for it.

Comment: You didn't include it in the question so I didn't know, and yes, the only way I know of that can remove those variable is change to class and use subclass for it, if you wish to stick with struct then you have to keep it, but can treat both as a single protocol type if you want (same as using parent class as type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably this is what you need, maybe you are thinking too hard on it:

```
struct Actions: Decodable {
    let upvote: Status
    let read: Status

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case upvote
        case read
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        self.upvote = try container.decode(Status.self, forKey: .upvote) {
        self.read = try container.decode(Status.self, forKey: .read)
    }
}

struct Status: Decodable {
    let delete: Bool
    let update: Bool
    let read: Bool
    let create: Bool
}
```

Comment: going with struct option for now.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to write a custom initialiser and to explicitly define the Coding Keys.

You can simply write

```
struct Response: Codable {

    let actions: Actions

    struct Actions : Codable {
        let upvote: Element
        let read: Element

        struct Element: Codable {
            let delete: Bool
            let read: Bool
            let create: Bool
            let update: Bool
        }
    }
}
```